# cloud prediction and local prediction doesn't return the same result

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I trained an image classifier with tensorflow and deployed it in the cloud. When i perform a prediction locally i get a result and when i perform a batch prediction using my deployed model i get a different result.

to perform the prediction locally i use this [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py)

to perform the prediction with the cloud i first resize my image and convert it to a float32 array (the model is trained with that type) and save it as a JSON file using the following :

```
import skimage, json
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage


with open('xxx.jpg', 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(f) as image:
        resized_image = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [299,299])



converted_image = skimage.img_as_float32(resized_image).tolist()

with open('request.json','w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump({"image": converted_image}, jsonfile)
```

and then i upload the request in my cloud bucket and create a job for the prediction as follows:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction "test_batch_prediction" \
                       --model "xxx" \
                       --input-paths "gs://path/to/my/request/request.json" \
                       --output-path "gs://path/to/where/prediction/will/be/saved/prediction_results/" \
                       --region "europe-west1" \
                       --data-format "text"
```

i think the problem is in resizing the image and converting it to float32 since i'm not using the same methods as tensorflow when performing the training or local prediction. Can this be the problem ? or is there something else i need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The script you used locally normalized the pixel values between 0 and 255 (mean defaults to 0):

normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

The code you used to upload to cloudml for online prediction is missing the normalization step. Add this:

converted_image = converted_image / 255.0